# AudioKit - Issues getting specific frequencies (above 20kHz)

Tags: ios, swift, audio, input, audiokit

I got a small problem using the [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io) framework:

----> I can't get the AudioKit framework to pick up special frequencies above and below a specific amount. (*frequency below `100Hz` & above `20kHz`*)

---

Edit: I've tested some **frequency-tracker** apps on my iOS device combined with some **online-tonegenerator tools** to check if my iPhone microphone is able to pick up those frequency above 20000Hz... And it is.

But using the default `frequency tracker` code snippets: Frequency above 20000Hz can not be picked up by AudioKit.

```
mic = AKMicrophone()
tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
AudioKit.output = silence
AudioKit.start()
```

---

```
print(tracker.frequency)
```

---> Is this is a **limitation of the AudioKit framework**, a limitation of the **default iOS-device settings**- or is **there maybe another way to** achieve getting those frequencies?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation in AudioKit.  The Frequency Tracker is based on a soundpipe opcode called [ptrack](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Soundpipe/modules/ptrack.c) which is in turn based off [Csound's ptrack](http://www.csounds.com/manualOLPC/ptrack.html).  You could modify the parameters to try to givie you rmore precision in the area of your concern, but if you are concerned with better results both low and high, that will be very processor intensive. Perhaps using two "banded" trackers for low and high would be better. There are always choices to be made and AudioKit's frequency tracker is geared towards typical audible ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Aurelius - Ahmm, what do you mean with `You could modify the parameters to try to givie you rmore precision in the area `? Which parameter should be modified? Thanks in advance. - Jane

Comment: Hey Aure - that shouldn't sound any kind of rude but I would be that happy if you give me a fast response to my latest question - I'm helpless without your help and so I'm not able to continue coding. @Aurelius Prochazka

Comment: Hi sorry, check these out: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Internals/Soundpipe/modules/ptrack.c#L18

Comment: Hey Aure, thanks for the answer but how can I edit the declaration of the variables? How to edit AudioKit source code??

Comment: All the source code is available on Github, you just change it and recompile it. If this is daunting, you may need to get some help, but its outside the bounds of AudioKit support.